# Como transformar um IPath em Path

Tags: java

Estou com dúvidas em como conseguir um *Path* através do *IPath*,

Tenho uma variável do tipo *IPath* mas tenho um método que requer um *Path*, tentei fazer um cast mas não tive sucesso, alguém conhece alguma solução ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim:

```
Path path = Paths.get(iPath.toFile().toURI());
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Daniel, funcionou perfeitamente